# Modernizr not working properly (applying fontface class in IE8)

Tags: css, font-face, modernizr

Well I've had a fun-filled 24 hours. Since asking this question yesterday: http://tinyurl.com/nkoqxfg I've been trying to isolate the problem, and finally I've narrowed it down to the following:

**Modernizr is incorrectly applying a class of fontface to the HTML element in IE8.**

Here is my site, with everything else stripped away: http://tinyurl.com/ose6pj8

Please take a look at the source code. Notice the last two CSS rules:

```
nav li a {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 4px;
}   

.fontface nav li a {
  font-family: 'Qwigley';
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 56px;
}
```

In any modern browser that supports @font-face, you should see the menu styled with Google font's 'Qwigly' script, and the correct font-size of 30px. In IE8 and any browser that doesn't support @font-face, you would expect to see a tiny font-size of 4px. (Modernizr in this case should apply a no-fontface class to the HTML element)

However, this is not the case. Mordernizr is incorrectly applying the fontface class, and as a result I'm getting huge 30px Arial text. Just checked, and the same problem is occurring with IE7.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in IE8 and any browser that doesn't support @font-face, you would expect to see a tiny font-size of 4px. (Modernizr in this case should apply a no-fontface class to the HTML element)

IE 8 *does* support `@font-face` – so expecting Modernizer to *not* set that class is just where *you are going wrong* here.

The *caveat* is that IE < 9 only supports fonts in EOT format – so see to it that you embed that version in your font embedding as well;

Or use a CSS selector that applies your custom font only if the `lt-ie9` class that you set for your `html` element via conditional comments is *not* present, something like

```
html:not(.lt-ie9) .fontface nav li a { /* … */ }
```

(IE only supports the `:not()` selector from v9 on anyway.)

Comment: excellent answer. worth noting that IE invented font-face, and supported it back in  IE 4

Comment: You, sir, are nothing short of a legend. As above, excellent, comprehensive answer. Problem now solved with a single line of code. Many thanks.